# If $A$ is a $7 \times 5$-matrix, what is the lowest possible dimension of Nul $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $A$ is a $7 \times 5$-matrix, what is the lowest possible dimension of Nul $A$?

We have that every column can be a pivot column, so we are left with no free variables. For the similar task

> If $A$ is a $3 \times 7$-matrix, what is the lowest possible dimension of Nul $A$?

it was easy to conclude with the answer "4". However, in this case, we have that every column can be a pivot column, no free variables. Would this imply that the lowest possible dimension is 0?

Comment: Yes, that is true. That was the basis of my argument.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: I deleted the comment when i realized that your last sentence was referring to the 7 x 5 matrix. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the rank-nullity theorem for an $m\ x \ n$ matrix $$Rank \ A + Nullity \ A = n$$

Since the Rank of a $7x5$ can be up to and including 5 , the Nullity can be 0.

Answer (score 1):

in $A$ $3\times 7$-matrix ,even if every column be pivot column , rank cannot exceed $3$, just as rank of $A$ in first case cannot exceed $5$.
moreover $Nul(A)=0$ implies rank if full, which is possible only in square matrix and since $3\times 7$ is not square so $Nul(A)$ cannot not be $0$
Therefore, $2\le dim(Nul(A)) \le 3$

Comment: Ok, I see your argument, but this is not what I asked.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: You just need to apply the rank-nullity theorem to complete the answer.

Comment: my answer was for 3x7 case

Comment: @AndrewThompson If this is not what you asked then why did you remarked it in blue in your question? That is very confusing...

Comment: yeap exactly it is

Comment: @DonAntonio What you refer to as "blue" is nothing but quotation, > is often used to quote on different webforums. There is nothing to confusing about it; given the title of the question and the text there is no way to misinterpret it.

Comment: Well @AndrewThompson, at least two here (ketan and I) thought that was integral part of the question. As you'd probably know, many of us read very quickly *only* the main question. This is why that was confusing, in particular that that scond blue part ends with a question mark...